# Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'distutils.util' - Dockerfile GDAL and geopandas python 3

Tags: python-3.x, dockerfile, gdal, geopandas, distutils

We going to have a AWS Lambda function (python3) created with Docker container (Elastic Container Registry)
When test the Lambda function, we have an error
**Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'distutils.util'**
What is wrong with Dockerfile?

```
ARG FUNCTION_DIR="/function"

FROM osgeo/gdal:ubuntu-small-latest as build-image

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y \
  g++ \
  make \
  cmake \
  unzip \
  libcurl4-openssl-dev


ARG FUNCTION_DIR

RUN mkdir -p ${FUNCTION_DIR}


COPY app/* ${FUNCTION_DIR}

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common gcc && \
    add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3.6 python3-distutils python3-pip python3-apt

RUN python3 -m pip install --target ${FUNCTION_DIR} awslambdaric
        
RUN python3 -m pip install --target ${FUNCTION_DIR} geopandas


FROM osgeo/gdal:ubuntu-small-latest

ARG FUNCTION_DIR

WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}

COPY --from=build-image ${FUNCTION_DIR} ${FUNCTION_DIR}

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3", "-m", "awslambdaric" ]

CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html#images-create-from-alt

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be (or at least there was) a [bug in setuptools](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2353).

I'm not 100% sure what caused it and if it's fixed or not, but I've resolved this problem with using the workaround proposed in the GitHib issue, which is to set the following environment variable:

`SETUPTOOLS_USE_DISTUTILS=stdlib`